# WordPress Child Theme not loading style.css

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a child theme and `functions.php` seems to be working but for some reason, the child theme isn't loading. I added the following in my functions.php and it does work, except it loads up the parent theme's `style.css` and not the child.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
});
```

Here's the top of my style.css in the child:

```
/*
Theme Name: Chaplin Child
Theme URI: https://my-site.com/
description: Child Theme
Template: Chaplin
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
Text Domain: stack-child
*/
```

Comment: Your code is telling WordPress to load the parent theme's stylesheet only and that's it. That's why it doesn't load the stylesheet from your child theme. The [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) has examples on how to load both stylesheets, have you tried them out yet?

Comment: Yes, I did. First version of the functions.php code didn't change anything. Second added the sheet but any style from the parent stylesheet overwrote the CSS in the child style sheet.

Comment: Then the problem is how you're writing the CSS rules for your child theme. This is a good read: [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 2):

Try this (in `functions.php`), this is from a *working*  child theme of mine and also enqueues the child theme stylesheet:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_scripts');

function register_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css'  );
}
```